# PHP fopen gives intermittent error failed to open stream: No space left on device

Tags: php, linux

This is the strange error i came across, my php script intermittently gives error **failed to open stream: No space left on device** whenever i try to generate text file and write some user generated content in it. But my Disk have plenty of Space.

Code i use is below:

```
$fp=fopen('../user1/dataProduct.txt','w');
fwrite($fp, 'Demo Text of Products');
fclose($fp);
```

If i do: df -H
[image: df -H Results]

Error:
        `PHP Warning:  fopen(../user1/dataProduct.txt): failed to open stream: No space left on device in /home/goashopping/public_html/sell/userprod.php on line 192
PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/goashopping/public_html/sell/userprod.php on line 195`

Please help me in fixing this issue.

Comment: I'm guessing your website has a quota set.

Comment: There is no quota set. while creation i chose unlimited when creating account in cpanel WHM

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check free inodes with `df -i`

```
you@yourbox:~$ df -i
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             532480   46391  486089    9% /
```

Filesystems with lots of little files usually run out of inodes way before running out of space. If this is your case you'll need to rebuild the filesystem and use `mkfs -i` to increase the available inodes on it.

Comment: It shows me on 
/dev/md2 = IUse% : 30 %
and
/dev/md1  = IUse% : 19% /tmp

Comment: This is it.. i deleted all tons of little 1kb files which was present in directory. Thanks

Comment: It's my problem!! I upgraded the hard drive and I solved

Comment: This was really helpful. was confused by message. turned out one small site was misconfigured and didn't delete session files. can't believe spent years with this.

Comment: How to rebuild the filesystem ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the disc does not have enough free inodes, check it:

```
df -i
```

And also read this [No space left on device](http://superrb.com/blog/2011/10/25/ubuntu-no-space-left-on-device-is-it-a-lie-or-have-i-run-out-of-inodes)

Comment: It shows me on /dev/md2 = IUse% : 30 % and /dev/md1 = IUse% : 19% /tmp and this issue is occurring sometime. not continuous error.

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it seems likely to be an inode problem, but I too experienced this issue intermittently. It occured in *only* one directory.

file_put_contents(/archive/ETG/content/original/173530/event/173530_unplanned_outage_rd_20150107_fd_20150107_152715_6.pdf): failed to open stream: No space left on device

```
$php --version  
PHP 5.3.28 (cli) (built: Jun 27 2014 15:36:16)  
$uname -ior  
2.6.18-238.19.1.el5 x86_64 GNU/Linux  

$df -ih /archive  
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on  
/dev/mapper/vg03--archive-archive  
                    669M     57M    613M    9% /archive  
$df -h /archive  
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/mapper/vg03--archive-archive  
                  5.2T  3.9T  1.1T  79% /archive  

$mount |grep archive  
/dev/mapper/vg03--archive-archive on /archive type ext3 (rw)  

$find /archive/ETG/content/original/173530/event -type d -prune -ls  
21610738 779840 drwxrwxrwx   3 gasconcoll gasconcoll 797769728 Jan  7 10:28 /archive    /ETG/content/original/173530/event  

$ls -altr /archive/ETG/content/original/173530/event/ |wc -l  
8000842  

$du -sh /archive/ETG/content/original/173530/event  
49G
```

I resolved the issue by doing the following:

```
$mkdir /archive/ETG/content/original/173530/event_new  
$chmod ugo+rwX /archive/ETG/content/original/173530/event_new  
$mv /archive/ETG/content/original/173530/event /archive/ETG/content/original/173530/event_old  
$mv /archive/ETG/content/original/173530/event_new /archive/ETG/content/original/173530/event  
$rsync -av /archive/ETG/content/original/173530/event_old/ /archive/ETG/content/original/173530/event
```

I no longer experience this error. I don't have enough time to dig further, but thought you might want to know what worked for me.